# Create profile photo for user on users facebook page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm struggling creating a profile picture on behalf of a user on facebook.

What endpoint do I need to use to update the profile image for a user on facebook? And what permissions do i need as well?

I have the access token and I'm using react native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Scopes**

1. if querying an App-Scoped User ID:

- None

2. If querying a User ID:

- User or Page access token for Facebook Login authenticated requests
- App access token for server-side requests
- Client access token for mobile or web client-side requests

3. If querying a Page-Scoped User ID:

- Page

## **Endpoint**

Upload the picture to an existing album (or create a new one) using the Graph API. Will look something like this:

```
$args = array('message' => 'Caption');
  $args['image'] = '@' . realpath("the_image.png");

  try {
    $data = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $args);
  }
  catch(Exception $e) {
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($e);
    print "</pre>";
  }
```

Then get the uploaded image via the Graph API and redirect to the image's link, add &makeprofile=1 to the querystring. The user will now be redirected to the profile image cropping page:

```
try {
  $pictue = $facebook->api('/'.$data['id']);
  header("Location: ".$pictue['link']."&makeprofile=1");
}
catch(Exception $e) {
  print "<pre>";
  print_r($e);
  print "</pre>";
}
```